# Confused by definition of ${}_{a}M$ where $a$ is a nonzero divisor and $M$ is an $R$-module.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, homological-algebra

The following is from Davis' *Lecture Notes in Algebraic Topology*. I'm very confused about the definition of ${}_{a}M=\{m\in M\mid am=0\}$. If $a$ is a non zero divisor then $am=0$ implies $m=0$, but then ${}_{a}M=\{0\}$.

> Is ${}_{a}M$ not always trivial? If it is always trivial is there a pedagogical reason for writing it in this way?

I understand that if $a$ was not a zero divisor then ${}_{a}M$ need not be trivial.

Here is the proposition for context.

[image]

Comment: If $a$ is not a zero divisor, then $ab = 0$ implies $b = 0$ when $b \in R$.  That is different from saying that $am = 0$ implies $m = 0$ for $m \in M$.

Comment: ah yes, could you possibly give an example? I see abstractly that need not be true but can't think of an obvious example

Comment: $2$ is not a zero divisor in $\mathbb{Z}$, but it satisfies $2m=0$ for all $m\in M=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to be careful to distinguish the ring structure on $R$ from the $R$-module structure on $M$. The example given in Captain Lama's comment generalizes: if $a\in R$ then $R/a$ is an $R$-module via $r\cdot [b] = [rb]$, and $a\cdot m = 0$ for all $m\in R/a$ wether or not $a$ is a zero-divisor in $R$.

To work out a concrete example, consider $R = \mathbb{Z}$ and $M = \mathbb{Z}/k$ where $k = p q$ is a product of two distinct primes. Then
$${}_pM = \{ [m] \in \mathbb{Z}/k\ |\ [pm] = 0\} = \{ [m] \in \mathbb{Z}/k\ |\ k\text{ divides } pm\} = q\cdot \mathbb{Z}/k \cong \mathbb{Z}/p.$$

This is consistent with the proposition, since $Tor(\mathbb{Z}/p, \mathbb{Z}/k) \cong Hom(\mathbb{Z}/p,\mathbb{Z}/k) \cong \mathbb{Z}/p$.